# How can I build dynamic URLs using them with routerLink in Angular 8?

Tags: angular8

I am trying to create links with a list of urls dynamically:

```
<span *ngIf="item.type=='link'">
          <a  class="nav-link" [routerLink]="item.routerLink" skipLocationChange>{{item.label}}</a>
        </span>
```

this solution is working fine when I am running dev in my localhost, but I get the following error when trying to build my library:

```
RROR: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" [ERROR ->][routerLink]="navBar.routerLink" skipLocationChange><img src="{{navBar.imagePath}}" height="40px" wid")
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("item':'nav-item dropdown'">
        <span *ngIf="item.type=='link'">
          <a  class="nav-link" [ERROR ->][routerLink]="item.routerLink" skipLocationChange>{{item.label}}</a>
        </span>
```

this is the list of my dependencies:

```
"@angular/animations": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.9",
```

Comment: item.routerLink this value are you getting from any API ? and is there any chance of having empty value ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported `import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';`?
[RouterModule](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule) this should work.
Or another way to make dynamic routes is you can call function and inside your `component.ts` file you can manage it.
**Example**

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class ExampleComponent {

    constructor(private router: Router,) {}

    routerLinkTo() {
        this.router.navigate(["/foo"]);
    }
}
```

Please check this example [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qoyavxdqdjd)

For more Router function please check Angular Documentation [here](https://v8.angular.io/guide/router)